# Rails flash.now hash with arbitrary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, hash, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I'm doing some basic validation and trying to add an arbitrary key to the flash hash (you can do that right?)

So in my controller I have this... "previousaction" posts to this page.

```
if params[:home_value] == "Select One"
    flash.now[:home_value] = "Please select a home value"
    render "previousaction"
else
    #set controller vars.. render this action as normal
end
```

And in the view:

```
<% if home_value %>
  <h6 id="notice" style="color:red;padding-bottom:5px;"><%= home_value %></h6>
  <%= label_tag "Estimated Home Value", "Estimated Home Value", :style => "color:red;"%><br/>
<% else %>
  <%= label_tag "Estimated Home Value", "Estimated Home Value" %><br/>
<% end %>
```

But I get this error when trying to load the controller action (the first time):

undefined local variable or method `home_value'

Tips appreciated :)

For Dave:

In a previous action/view I use flash[:notice] like this:

```
if params[:zip_code].length != 5
  flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid zipcode. Please enter your 5-digit zipcode"
  render "firstpage"
else
```

and then in the view

```
<% if notice %>
```

Is flash[:notice] a special flash key for rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`home_value` won't magically be associated with the `flash`, it's just being treated as a local variable; try accessing the flash hash with `:home_value` directly.

That said, what's the purpose of using an arbitrary key?

Comment: Dave great thanks that worked will accept in 4 min. I edited my question above to reflect a question I have about flash[:notice] and why rails recognizes it as notice in a view...   Purpose of arbitrary key is to place validations for specific information/params missing from a form submit. The form isn't resource backed at this point so I haven't been able to the nifty rails validation helpers.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Validation error messages are already stored under the model's `errors` instance variable as a hash; check it out :) If you're not using a model (meh, don't do that ;) just keep the messages in a regular hash--I'm not sure it's worth overload flash in that way, but might be wrong.